# Resolvent and spectrum of a self-adjoint extension

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

In [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.64.1855), they give the resolvent, spectrum, and eigenfunctions of the self-adjoint extension of the Laplacian on a rectangle that corresponds to a delta potential at an arbitrary point (items (5) through (9) on the second page).

Can someone point me to some references on how that's done? Does it follow from some standard results on self-adjoint extensions?

Comment: The link does not work for those who don't have subscription to PRL. One of the standard references on the subject is [this book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=cR6uhyqnpUQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Informally, you can think of self-adjoint extension as a finite-rank perturbation of the initial operator: it is this fact that allows to compute the quantities such as resolvent.